# WD Passport external device not recognized

Tags: windows, hard-drive, filesystem, external-hdd, format

I am getting following error when I connect my external HDD.

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
The file system wasn't safely closed on Windows. Fixing.
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
Failed to sync device /dev/sdc1: Input/output error
Failed to close volume /dev/sdc1: Input/output error
```

This started happening after I copied some data from a Windows machine.

Can someone please help me out, I want the data to be recovered.

Comment: To add to it, lsusb lists the hard disk when connected. And I tried recovering it on windows using chkdsk /F, but no luck

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Please run `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdc` , upload the output to http://paste.ubuntu.com, [edit] your question and add the link to the output.  (And I don't have good news: It looks like your HDD is dying...)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, it looks like the filesystem on your passport is corrupted. If chkdsk hasn't fixed the issue it would suggest that the filesystem is corrupted beyond repair (at least the repair offered by chkdsk).

If you still have the data on your windows machine, the quickest fix would probably be to reformat the drive and re-copy the data.

Comment: I/O errors usually come from hardware failure, rather than filesystem corruption...

Comment: I second the above opinion.  **Furthermore, the OP is asking to rescue his data, not irretrievably lose it!**